# How Does Gradle Pass Its Classpath When It Compiles Java?

Tags: java, gradle

Usually, when I see build tools (e.g. Ant) compile Java, I can see the javac process with a classpath. In the past, I’ve run into problems where the command line argument is too long due to system limitations. When I build code using Gradle and its Java plugin, I see no such process running.

How does Gradle pass along the classpath to the Java compiler? Does it do so via the command line, a manifest jar, or some other means? Is there a risk of the command line process being too long?